# How to use $dateToString in $group pipeline Mongodb Aggregation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using Mongodb 3.0 and i want to use `$dateToString` in specific format for example `Thu 10-Nov-2016`. Here is my code

```
collection.aggregate([
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: { 
                month: { $month: "$onDate" }, 
                day: { $dayOfMonth: "$onDate" }, 
                year: { $year: "$onDate" } 
            },
            totalSearch: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { $limit: 10 },
    { $sort: { '_id.year': -1,'_id.month': -1,'_id.day': -1 } },
    //***Here i am want to use $dateToString with $project corresponding to $group._id****////
    { $project: { $dateToString: { format: 'xxxxxxxx', date: xxxxxxxxx } } } 
],
    function(err, dayWise) {
        if (err)
            cb(err);
        console.log('dayWises',dayWise);
            cb(null, dayWise);
    }
)
```

Comment: dateToString takes date as parameter not date integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the $concat in the project stage to get the date string out of the group id date values to format the date string.

```
{
    $project: {
        'value': {
            '$concat': [{
                    $substr: ["$_id.year", 0, -1]
                },
                "-", {
                    $substr: ["$_id.month", 0, -1]
                },
                "-", {
                    $substr: ["$_id.day", 0, -1]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can apply the $dateToString in the group pipeline along with the other values as id.

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            month: {
                $month: "$onDate"
            },
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$onDate"
            },
            year: {
                $year: "$onDate"
            },
            formattedDateString: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d",
                    date: '$onDate'
                }
            }
        },
        totalSearch: {
            $sum: 1
        }
}
```

Comment: can concat value as `Thu 10-Nov-2016` rather than `2016-11-10' in first example and second example is not working.

Comment: Nope, you cant apply custom formatting in the concat. what error do you get when using the second example ?

Comment: thanks for reply and second example work fine that was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant get the format you specified,instead you can get "2014-01-01" this format,1st of all you have not passed a date in your group stage ISO to work with dateTostring,Check this

```
collection.aggregate([{
          $group: {
                   _id: { month: { $month: "$onDate" }, day: { $dayOfMonth: "$onDate" }, year: { $year: "$onDate" } },date : {"$first":"$onDate"}
                        totalSearch: { $sum: 1 }
                        },
                    },
                    { $limit: 10 },
                    { $sort: { '_id.year': -1,'_id.month': -1,'_id.day': -1 } },

        {$project:{$dateToString:{format:"%Y-%m-%d",date: $onDate}}


} 
                ],
                function(err, dayWise) {
                    if (err)
                        cb(err);
                    console.log('dayWises',dayWise);
                    cb(null, dayWise);
                })
```